# Change Montserrat bold font

Tags: fonts, bold

I want to use Montserrat ExtraLight as the main font of my report and because the default bold style is too bold, I would like to use Montserrat Regular as bold style. I am using \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage[defaultfam,extralight,tabular,lining]{montserrat}.

Could you help me what I should change to use Montserrat Regular as bold font?

Cheers,
Marina

Comment: One option is to use XeLaTeX / LuaTeX and to specify the bold font explicitly with `fontspec`.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use also Montserrat as math font?

Answer (score 2):

There is no package option for this, but you can use a lower level setting.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  defaultfam,
  extralight,
  tabular,
  lining
]{montserrat}

\makeatletter
\def\bfseries@sf{m}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Normal text (should be extralight)

\textbf{Boldface text} (should be medium)

\end{document}
```

[image]